# Selenium IDE 1.4.1 throwing security error when uploading a local file

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

with this simple configuration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://localhost:8080/" />
<title>basic</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/upload.html</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>C:\Temp\harmony\tests\02.basic\config.xml</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//input[@value='Upload']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=go to home</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=New order</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: code -> 1000, INDEX_SIZE_ERR -> 1, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR -> 2, HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR -> 3, WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR -> 4, INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR -> 5, NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR -> 6, NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR -> 7, NOT_FOUND_ERR -> 8, NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR -> 9, INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR -> 10, INVALID_STATE_ERR -> 11, SYNTAX_ERR -> 12, INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR -> 13, NAMESPACE_ERR -> 14, INVALID_ACCESS_ERR -> 15, VALIDATION_ERR -> 16, TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR -> 17, DATA_CLONE_ERR -> 25, message -> Security error, result -> 2152924136, name -> NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR, filename -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/atoms.js, lineNumber -> 8910, columnNumber -> 0, location -> JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/atoms.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 8910, inner -> null, data -> null
```

This happens after upgrating to Firefox 8. Before that the test worked just fine. The Selenium IDE version is 1.4.1 and this seems to be the last one.

Please, help.

Thank you.

Martin

**EDIT:** The line from the error is: `a.value = d`. Here is the whole function:

```
core.events.replaceText_ = function(a, b) {
  bot.events.fire(a, "focus", {bubble:!1});
  bot.events.fire(a, "select");
  var c = bot.dom.getAttribute(a, "maxlength"), d = b;
  c != null && (c = parseInt(c), b.length > c && (d = b.substr(0, c)));
  if(bot.dom.isElement(a, goog.dom.TagName.BODY)) {
    if(a.ownerDocument && a.ownerDocument.designMode && (new String(a.ownerDocument.designMode)).toLowerCase() == "on") {
      a.innerHTML = d
    }
  }else {
    a.value = d
  }
  try {
    bot.events.fire(a, "change")
  }catch(e) {
  }
};
```

Comment: It would probably help to look up `chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/atoms.js`, line 8910 ;)

Comment: @Wladimir Palant: can't determine the correct line. Line 8910 is ` a.value = d` which souldn't trigger an exception

Comment: Given that this is `NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR` - it might be, if `a` is something from a different document. It is probably best if you edit the context of this line into your question.

Comment: This sounds like Selenium bug #2826: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2826

Comment: @Ross Patterson: yep! this is the same bug. thanks, can you move it to an answer so i can accept it. thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like [Selenium bug #2826](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2826).

Comment: One of the developers just checked in a fix for this bug: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=15134.  It will be in the next release, probably to be called 1.5.0.

Answer (score 4):

Find the file atom.js at firefox extensions directory and search by the function body:

```
core.events.replaceText
```

So, look for the line with:

```
a.value = d
```

and change it to:

```
XPCNativeWrapper(a).value = d;
```

It will fix the bug.