# How do I edit atoms.js when using Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I have the same Firefox 8 upload issue with Selenium as described here: [Selenium IDE 1.4.1 throwing security error when uploading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149403/selenium-ide-1-4-1-throwing-security-error-when-uploading-a-local-file)

The solution to the problem is to edit the atoms.js file, which I can do for Selenium IDE.

However, I'm also using Selenium RC, and want to know how to do the equivalent thing there.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the atoms.js file.

It's here:

http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/f09fbab515806073

Happy times.