# Selenium IDE 1.7.1 throwing security error when uploading a local file

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

This may be related to this post:

[Selenium IDE 1.4.1 throwing security error when uploading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149403/selenium-ide-1-4-1-throwing-security-error-when-uploading-a-local-file)

But after a windows 7 update last night, I am getting the following error when uploading a file using selenium IDE 1.7.1:

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: code -> 1000, INDEX_SIZE_ERR -> 1, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR -> 2, HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR -> 3, WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR -> 4, INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR -> 5, NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR -> 6, NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR -> 7, NOT_FOUND_ERR -> 8, NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR -> 9, INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR -> 10, INVALID_STATE_ERR -> 11, SYNTAX_ERR -> 12, INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR -> 13, NAMESPACE_ERR -> 14, INVALID_ACCESS_ERR -> 15, VALIDATION_ERR -> 16, TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR -> 17, DATA_CLONE_ERR -> 25, message -> Security error, result -> 2152924136, name -> NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR, filename -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/atoms.js, lineNumber -> 8864, columnNumber -> 0, location -> JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/atoms.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 8864, inner -> null, data -> null
```

Running Firefox 11.0

The selenium command is:

```
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>id=VisioFile</td>
<td>C:\Selenium\Simple_File.vdx</td>
</tr>
```

Until last night and a windows update, this was working perfectly. Could potentially be the reboot having updated firefox or selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression from 1.7.0.  It was [fixed in 1.7.2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3549) which was released earlier today.